# php do not fetch new data from database after adding item

Tags: php

I working on a very simple form project, I send items using ajax and save them on the database using PHP `insert` query, then by clicking a button I fetch data using ajax from another PHP file using `SELECT` query, the problem is when I want to get new data the PHP query doesn't update data and it returns old data if I check the file whit out using ajax and I put the URL like `mysite.com/getdata.php` it still returns old data and I have to refresh this page until it fetches new data, I don't have any error or warning in my javascript code or PHP and I have no idea why it doesn't get new data whit new request and I have to refresh the URL till fetches new data.

It worked correctly local I see this bug when I upload my code to the server

My `getdata.php` file code:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "projectform";
$password = "jtq*o2ZL7qBPt_HS";
$dbname = "projectform";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    $responseData = json_encode(array(
        "status"  => $status,
        "message" => "Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error,
        "data"    => null,
    ));
    die($responseData);
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM form_data";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

$data = array();

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  // output data of each row
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      $data[] = array(
          'id'      => $row["id"],
          'Title'   => $row["title"],
          'address' => $row["address"],
          'photo'   => $row["p_date"],
          'phone'   => $row["phone"],
          'detail'  => $row["detail"],
          'create'  => $row["created_at"],
          'status'  => $row["status"],
        );
  }
  $status = "success";
  $message = "";
  $response = $data;
} else {
  $data = null;
  $status = "error";
  $message = "NO data found.";
}
$conn->close();

$responseData = json_encode(array(
    "status"  => $status,
    "message" => $message,
    "data"    => $response,
));

die($responseData);
```

Comment: (1) Maybe your browser is caching your request. You can open the Console of the browser, in the Network tab, stick "Disable cache" and try again. (2) If your website is put behind a proxy, please check the proxy cache and try to disable the proxy cache first.

Comment: it's because of cache, how to disable it in PHP?
because I can't control my users to `disable cache`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using pure PHP, you can try to disable browser cache like this:

```php
header("Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT");
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Connection: close");
```